# Geotagging video

Tags: export, google-earth, video, geotagging

I want to import a geotagged video to a point or have a point and attach a video to it, so that I can play the video by clicking on the point. Is there any solution in QGIS?

I also want to know if there is any possibility to export a map with geotagged photo to Google Earth format. I export as KML but it just exports the points without the tagged photo.

Does anyone know the solutions?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which emphasizes the importance of asking One question per Question. Questions should not only state a task but also state what you have attempted to resolve it, and indicate where you are stuck. Multiple paragraphs and a graphic are likely to be necessary. Sometimes a thoroughly researched Question doesn't get asked, because then Answer becomes evident.

Comment: actions in qgis will do this https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/training_manual/create_vector_data/actions.html#basic-fa-creating-an-action

Comment: @Mapperz probably posting this as an answer would help others finding the solution easier?

Comment: This python tool will create a KML in the directory of geotagged images.  Once the KML is open in Google Earth you can click the image location and the image will open in a viewer in Google Earth.  The KML will need to travel with the images since the image paths are relative to the KML location (the images are not stored inside the KML).  https://github.com/ShuksanGeomatics/Geotagged_Image_Tools